# Email .pdf files based on file name using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Morning,

I am currently building a process to email 10,000+ statements to clients. So far I have created the statement in `SQL`/`SSRS` and have written a `PowerShell` script to loop through and run each statement and save as a `.pdf` with the client reference number as the filename.

I now have a folder containing all of the files along with a `.csv` file containing the client reference number and the email address to send it to.

Is it within the capabilities of `PowreShell` to send all of the `.pdf` files to the email addresses contained within the `.csv` with the relevant attachemnt?

If so I would be extremely grateful if anybody could suggest some further reading - I've got straightforward emails with attachments working but I can't even find anything close online to what I'm trying to do.

Many thanks

Additional detail.

Filename is a 7 digit number. The .csv file at the moment contains the filename in column 1 e.g. 1234567 and in column 2 the email address. This could be changed though if needed.

Comment: You'll need to provide some details about the csv columns or a set of sample data, as well as the format of the pdf file names if you want us to show you some useful examples

Comment: If your statements are in SSRS, you may be able to create a data-driven subscription to handle generating the statements and emailing them all in one (you'll need the email addresses associated with the reference number in your database, instead of a CSV file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds fairly straight forward. You can import the CSV file like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv ";" -path .\test.csv -header "id","email"
```

I'm assuming your CSV is seperated with `;` in this case. The header is added so we can address the fields with those properties afterwards.

Then loop over it and send your email by using the `id` and `email` property:

```
foreach ($item in $csv) {
    $filename = "$($item.id).pdf"
    send-mailmessage -to $item.email -attachments $filename -body "blah" -subject "blah" -from "me@foo.com"
}
```

Comment: Great. That does make sense as I've used Send-MailMessage. I'm still not seeing where it attaches each relevant .pdf file though (each one is named with the relevant client number).

Comment: I updated the answer to include the actual sending of the message. The trick is the -attachments parameter and of course, composing the correct filename using the ID. You might have to include a path if the file isn't in the current directory.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. Think I almost have this working now. Really appreciate you taking the time to understand the issue.